# Expression for average energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Let $| \mathrm{b}\rangle$ be a basis .
In the book *Theory of atomic structure spectra*  by Cowan at page 112 ,eq (4.38)
he defines
$$
E_{a v}=\frac{\sum_{\mathrm{b}}\langle\mathrm{b}|\mathrm{H}| \mathrm{b}\rangle}{\text { number of basis functions }} 
\tag {4.38}
$$

then he claims

> Since the trace of a matrix is invariant under all orthogonal transformations, and in particular under that transformation  which diagonalizes $\mathrm{H},(4.38)$ may also be written in the form
> $$
> \mathrm{E}_{\mathrm{av}}=\frac{\sum_{\text {states }} \mathrm{E}^{\mathrm{k}}}{\text { number of states }} \text {, } \tag {4.39}
> $$

How to proof that $(4.38)$ is equal to $(4.39)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eq. 4.38 is nothing but the trace of $H$ written out in a chosen basis $\{\vert b_i\rangle\}$

$$E_\mathrm{av} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \langle b_i \vert H\vert b_i\rangle 
=\mathrm{tr}\{H\}.$$

The average energy does not change under transformations of $H$ into its eigenbasis $H\rightarrow \tilde{H}=UHU^\dagger$ with some unitary $U$. This can be shown by noting that trace is invariant under cyclic permutation

$$\mathrm{tr}\{H\} =  \mathrm{tr}\{H\underbrace{U^\dagger U}_{=\mathbb{1}}\} = \mathrm{tr}\{UHU^\dagger\}.$$

Since $UHU^\dagger=\mathrm{diag}(E_1,\dots,E_N)$ is simply a diagonal matrix, one thus arrives at eq. 4.39,

$$E_\mathrm{av} =\sum_i E_i.$$

Comment: How do we know that the matrix H is diagonalizable? In  order to a matrix be diagonalazable all his eingenvectors  has to be linearly independent wich is not always the case if we have degenerate eingenvalues

Comment: $H$ is hermitian. Hermitian matrices can always be diagonalized. You're right that it can have degenerate eigenvalues. But that does not have anything to do with diagonalizability. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363421/prove-that-hermitian-matrices-are-diagonalizable